# Grid View Item Presenter

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, winrt-xaml, windows-10

How could I specify Grid View Item Presenter ?

(ScreenShot) I think I've to change HorizantalContentAlignment of GridViewItemsPresenter.

```
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:mymodel">
   <StackPanel BorderThickness="4,0,0,0" BorderBrush="{x:Bind Color}"Padding="4,0,0,0" Margin="0,2" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
   <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
   <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Date}" Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"/>
   <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Type}" Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"/>
   <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Dls}" Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"/>
  </StackPanel>
 </DataTemplate>
</GridView.ItemTemplate>
```

[image: auto alignment]

Comment: can you add some xaml ?

Comment: you can add empty grid in data template and manage him width :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this

```
<GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
```